# Displaying user uploaded html content - Security Issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a feature where user can upload html file which I then read its content via PHP and send it to the third party API as a string. Now before I send it to the API I want to generate a preview of the HTML they uploaded to the user so they can press Confirm button to send it.

The HTML files should be mostly letter templates but users can modify the html and add some script tags or inject other malicious code that might harm my website while displaying for preview. Is there a way I can avoid this?

I thought about stripping  tags but what if they have onclick events within html elements?

Comment: Best solution I think is to display it in an iframe with the sandbox property.

Comment: when you want only a preview, than save the data in the session or anything else, before you make a preview and then use the saved data for send to the api!

Comment: Are they the only ones that can see the preview? If so, what good would it do them to inject code that only affects themselves?

Comment: @Pat basically only admin users can do it, so one admin user could do it and others can see the preview of it later even after its sent.

Comment: Actually, on second thought - when you say `malicious code that might harm my website while displaying for preview` what _exactly_ do you mean? Previewing a template won't harm your server it would, at most, affect the user who is previewing it. So you could accept that. On the other hand, you might want to protect users from being tricked to preview a malicious template, in which case, running it in restricted mode (sandboxed iframe) will probably be as safe as it gets. This _might_ break some legit functionality in there but it's still a preview only, so whatever.

Comment: OK, that comment about admin users came in exactly when I posted mine. In that case, your best bet really is to restrict the template. You probably don't want your admin users to be infected.

Comment: You could research how to render HTML page as an image server side, and just send the image to the browser.

Comment: @Vld makes senes. What I meant is like injecting a button that redirects elsewhere or having an onclick event that does something.

Comment: @vld : the content will still be loaded from the OPs domain, so reading cookies is still possible.

Comment: In addition to the sandboxed iframe, I would be in support of finding an HTML-analyzing PHP library that only allows certain tags like `<b>`, `<a>`, or `<i>` and throws an error if it finds others.

Comment: @GGio I'd say accept the risk the template might not work as intended. It's better than opening up to a XSS. You can't really display something like that anyway - no way do distinguish between benevolent and malevolent scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Id start with something like this to strip scripts and comments:

```
$htmlblacklist[] = '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si'; //bye bye javascript
$htmlblacklist[] = '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'; //goodbye comments

//now apply blacklist
$value = preg_replace($htmlblacklist, '', $value);
```

For inline events, you should use DOMDocument, as it understands HTML whereas Regex is shooting in the dark.

In reality, you could use DOMDocument for all of it, and not use Regex at all. Load up the HTML in a DOMDocument object, and iterate through the tree, removing what you want.

Comment: That actually makes sense. Since my file does not expect any attributes on the element I can just iterate through and remove all atributes and just leave the element tags. I can also strip <script> tags which then leaves plain <style> and <html> tags with html elements. I will try it out and try few variations to see if it works. Thanks alot

Comment: @GGio Someone could still add javascript through attributes (i.e. `onload="<javascript code>"`)

Comment: White listing is always more secure than black listing. This is because black listing requires you to chase your tail every time. You're removing scripts and comments but what about attributes on elements? `onclick="/* malicious JS */"` You now have to blacklist this. But what about the next vulnerability - `<img src="invalid" onerror="/* malicious JS */"` once you deal with that there would be another one. It's always a chase and you'll always be behind. When never know if you've missed an attack vector. And you most likely would have.

Comment: @Vld I am talking about using DOMDocument object to loop through all elements and remove ALL associated attributes with them. Only keep those attributes that I will need.

Comment: @GGio my comment was aimed at the answer. Your proposed solution _is_ whitelisting. It's most likely going to work, depending on whether or not the attributes you expect are possibly attack vectors or not. Either way, though, you will dramatically decrease your attack surface, so even if they _are_ potentially dangerous, it'd be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% this will work for you, but it seems that rendering the HTML as an SVG onto a canvas will restrict the contents to within your requirements (no scripts, no loading outside sources).

See more documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

> You might wonder how this can be secure, in light of concerns about
>   the possibility of reading sensitive data out of the canvas. The
>   answer is this: this solution relies on the fact that the
>   implementation of SVG images is very restrictive. SVG images aren't
>   allowed to load any external resources, for example, even ones that
>   appear to be from the same domain. Resources such as raster images
>   (such as JPEG images) or s have to be inlined as data: URIs.
>
> In addition, you can't include script in an SVG image, so there's no
>   risk of access to the DOM from other scripts, and DOM elements in SVG
>   images can't receive input events, so there's no way to load
>   privileged information into a form control (such as a full path into a
>   file  element) and render it, then pull that information out by
>   reading the pixels.

Comment: What if the HTML contains an image tag that loads the image from lets say amazon services (public url), that would also be rejected based on the description.

Comment: You would then need to encode the URL to a uri, here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/99y9j8o1/1/

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the library that handles this. Have not yet fully tested it but based on its description it might be the one: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FileReader` to read the contents of the file, and an `iframe` to safely (or not) view it:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener(
    'click',
    function() {
      let iframe = document.createElement("iframe"),
        holder = document.querySelector("#iframeholder"),
        sandboxFlags = [
          ...document.querySelectorAll('.sandbox-flags:checked')
        ].map(_ => _.value).join(','),
        file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();


      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        iframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
        iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("srcdoc", this.result);
        /*
         * Sandboxing is not allowed in code snippets
         * iframe.setAttribute("sandbox", sandboxFlags);
         *
         */
        console.log(`sandbox=${sandboxFlags}`);

        while (holder.firstChild)
          holder.removeChild(holder.firstChild);

        holder.appendChild(iframe);
        
      }, false);

      reader.readAsText(file);
  },
  false);
```

```css
label {
  display: block
}

#iframeholder>iframe {
  border:1px solid black;
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="browse" type="file" >
</div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sandbox-flags" value='allow-script' />allow-scripts
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sandbox-flags" value='allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox' />allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sandbox-flags" value='allow-forms' />allow-forms
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sandbox-flags" value='allow-modals' />allow-modals
  </label>
<div>
  <button type="button">Preview</button>
</div>
<div id="iframeholder"></div>
```